# C++ Data validation before using initialization list

Tags: c++, validation, constructor, initialization

I'm implementing a Triangle class whose attributes are three private objects of a Point class.
So far I'm using an initializer list in the Triangle constructor to initialize those three Points. The problem is that I have to identify if it is a valid Triangle at the moment of creating it (checking if the sum of two sides is bigger than the third). How can I validate that?
Note: I could change my Triangle Constructor to look like this:

```
Triangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

But I'd really like to know how to do it if it looks like this:

```
Triangle(p1, p2, p3)
```

My code looks like this

```
class Point {
private:
   double x; 
   double y;
public:
   Point():x(0.0), y(0.0) {};
   Point(double x0, double y0):x(x0), y(y0){};
   double distance(Point p) {//distance between two points};
   //getters
   //setters
 };

class Triangle {
private:
   Point v1;
   Point v2;
   Point v3;
public:
   Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3): 
                                         v1(p1.getX(), p1.getY()),
                                         v2(p2.getX(), p2.getY()),
                                         v3(p3.getX(), p3.getY())  {
       //Edit
       if v1.distance(v2) + v2.distance(v3) <= v1.distance(v3) {
            //This is not a valid triangle, assign correct values to
            //v1, v2 and v3
       }
   }
   //Other methods.
 };
```

Comment: What would the constructor do if it's an invalid triangle?

Comment: _"How can I validate that?"_  Are you asking _how to know_ if a triangle's points are invalid, or are you asking _what to do_ when they are invalid?

Comment: I'd do what you're doing, test for validity in the body of the constructor and throw an exception if it's not valid. Place the onus on the caller to test ahead of time or clean up the exception.

Comment: @zerocukor287 for simplicity I would only show a message that the triangle is invalid and assign valid values for the triangle.

Comment: I can't see how the test for validity would be any different if you used raw coordinates or `Points.`

Comment: @DrewDormann  I'm trying to find out if the sum of two sides are bigger than the third one BEFORE creating the triangle (but checking that inside the constructor)

Comment: *for simplicity I would only show a message that the triangle is invalid* I recommend against this. If the caller doesn't provide a valid triangle, don't give the caller a broken object. Some dumb-<expletive deleted> will not bother checking and keep going, using the broken object as though it's a valid one and then have to go bug hunting somewhere else in the code when the error becomes brutally obvious rather than closer to where the bug really is.

Comment: *I'm trying to find out if the sum of two sides are bigger than the third one BEFORE creating the triangle* That I'm 100% down with. BUT it raises the great question of what do you plan to do on failure? How I'd solve the problem as asked depends a lot on what I was going to do in the failure case.

Comment: Side note: Ask a new question and make sure you include the *I'm trying to find out if the sum of two sides are bigger than the third one BEFORE creating the triangle* to the question. It's very important information answerers need to have in order to provide answers you can use. Per the wording in the question, Fantastic Mr Fox's answer is perfect, so it's too late to drastically change the question by adding this vital and game-changing information.

Comment: Hmmm. Once I take the title into account, that addition might not be as game-changing as I thought. Just a different take on the question.  That said, you don't want questions with two valid interpretations because that leads to dueling correct answers and confused future readers.

Comment: Off topic, but if consider making the coordinates of the point class public and getting rid of the getter/setters. Although the difference in C++ is quite small, a point is rather a struct than a class.

Comment: Consider using `struct Point { double x, y; };` and making `distance()` a non-member function.

Comment: _"I'm trying to find out if the sum of two sides are bigger than the third one"_ You will discover that _that_ is impossible, when the triangle is defined by three points. There are no possible three points that can produce that scenario.  You might want to check if the three points are colinear, however.

Answer (score 6):

Checking and only creating valid objects through construction is very common in c++. There is even a core guideline about it; [If a constructor cannot construct a valid object, throw an exception](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c42-if-a-constructor-cannot-construct-a-valid-object-throw-an-exception).

So in your case, you could provide something like this:

```
bool is_valid_triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    ...  // Implementation
}

...


Triangle::Triangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) :
    v1{p1}, // requires copy constructor for Point which you should add
    v2{p2}, v3{p3}
{
    if (!is_valid_triangle(p1, p2, p3)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Points provided are not a triangle");
    }
    ... // Set up class
}
```

Then the user needs to check if they are creating valid triangles:

```
try {
    Triangle t{p1, p2, p3};
    ... // operate with t
} catch(...) {
    ... // Warn the user
}
```

Comment: Let's suppose it's a valid triangle, how do I set up the class if I need to do it through the initializer list in the constructor? Or the only way to do it is to implement Point as a struct, as mentioned in the comments?

Comment: Add a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to your point class then assign your internal points in the initialiser list of Triangle. If you don't know what those terms mean, google them, and check the link that comes up on cppreference.